# updating SUM with latest data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet that I am working on.

It is a data caputure tool that will enable me to track the Value Added (VA) Score of student data vs their target. For example, a student with a target of 5 that returns a paper with a score of 5 would have '0' VA - We haven't added any value to their learning, they have achieved what they should have.

There are 3 points of assessment that I need to track across the year and would like the 'VA' column to be updated following each assessment point.

I need a function that will allow me to subtract the AP score from the target (T) and give the VA score but that will update the VA column as the new AP scores are entered.

Any thoughts?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHgw.png]

Comment: What are you using - Excel, Google Sheets? And what have you tried?

Comment: We are using Excel. We just decided that we wanted to use the latest AP data rather than the highest score, which we used previously using the MAX function. Other than just running the SUM function for the last AP column minus the Target, which wouldn't keep a running VA score, I'm lost!

Comment: As it is your question is hard to understand as regarding the function/formula that you need.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: I see. We have previously used:

Comment: =MAX(G7:I7)-F7 - This gave us the VA score based on the students' highest score over the year. The issue with this is that the highest score could have been in an assessment, based on a key strength of the student at the beginning of the year, which wouldn't represent an accurate figure for the year

Comment: =AVERAGE(G7:I7)-F7 Which gives us the average of the three but what I really need is a formula that will give (G7,H7,I7)-F7 but prioritise H7 and then I7 when that data is inputted respectively - I hope that makes sense and sorry if i'm gong about this the wrong way! I've tried for days to search a solution!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1755016/edit) with the additional information as comments can become outdated and be removed.

Comment: maybe the answers to this question (asked about 5 days ago) will give you some ideas: https://superuser.com/questions/1754360/find-column-of-the-last-appearance-of-a-value

Answer (score 0):

For what follows, consider the table in the picture, the one showing the conditional formatting, let's say the spreadsheet cells used are row 3 through row 27 for the data, the "T" column is column A, the "VA" column is column E, and the totals at the bottom are in row 28 (cells A28:E28).

What it seems you want:  The data rows will be filled to some extent, presumably at least on row (row 3), the columns (B, C, D) will fill over time, not all at once, so you want the "VA" column to accommodate that rather than needing a simple "fill those columns all at once and see the row result", and you want the totals row to perform similarly, reflecting each change as time passes. In the totals row, you want averages of the values currently in the data region.

So, the "VA" column needs a formula that adds the B:D values present and either subtracts a count of the existing of the three possible entries times the "T" column value to give the total difference between the "AP" scores sum and however many of the "T" column value as there are B:D entries:

```
=SUM(B5:D5)  -  A5 * COUNT(B5:D5)
```

The totals row has two basic formulas, one for columns A:D, and one for the "VA" column. The first simply sums all the rows in each column and divides by a count of however many values are present in the different columns at any given time. So column B might have 14 values while columns C and D have, say, 8 and 2. Each column's formula does a count for that column so they do not interfere with each other. The "VA" column uses the formula it uses in each of the rows. The formula for columns A:D is:

```
=SUM(B3:B9)  /  COUNT(B3:B9)
```

One must then format the cells in the "VA" column, above the totals row, to have zero decimal places and the cells in the totals row, including the "VA" column, to have one decimal place in the numbers.

Something important here about rounding and displaying values:

1. When displaying values using a given format, the actual value stays whatever it was (5.8869825534 perhaps) even though it displays as 6 or 5.9, say. If you do this, reliably do it, not carelessly, you can actually just add numbers in a column like the "VA" column since they have their full actual values hiding under the displayed value. So a -1.66...7 shows -2 but is really still the -1.66...7 and can be used like that.
2. If you round them instead, the the -1.66...7 becomes a real -2 and just adding the "VA" column would become a real problem.
3. You want to ignore both sets of thoughts though and do the calculations on "the whole" as I laid out above because of the way the values will only fill in over time. While doing so, a value of +1 in the "VA" column has a different effect on the true, at the moment, overall "VA" value depending upon whether there are one, two, or all three possible entries present in that row. "Weighted averages" is the general topic, and is why I did the overall calculations on columns and then used those totals get the overall current "VA" score.
4. And no matter how you manage the display being no decimals in the data rows, and then one decimal place in the totals row, someone is going to do some calculation for some (don't say stupid, don't say stupid)... obtuse... reason and something won't match causing them to decide you did something wrong, not them misunderstanding things.

All the above said, the form clearly involves a number of knowledge areas, each with its own body of data and calculations. Once you have the above formulas in place, you can copy the region and paste it onto any same size region. And for larger regions (maybe they have five "AP" columns), paste them onto the rightmost five columns in the region, then copy the left three columns of those five into the leftmost column to its left. (Looks like the conditional formatting does not exist in that first column, so this will produce a first column with none, and overwrite the third column with an "AP" column and its standard conditional formatting. The modify the cell addresses in the formulas. All set.